# BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted | BouncyCastle

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

I'm trying to decrypt data that is encrypted with AES/SIC/PKCS7Padding. I'm making use of BouncyCastleProvider to achieve this, but on decryption BadPaddingException is thrown.
Here's the code i'm using to decrypt, am i doing something wrong? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
public class AesEncryption {
    
    public static String decrypt(String aesKey, String cipherText) {
        try {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

            Cipher dcipher;
            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(aesKey), "AES");
            dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/SIC/PKCS7Padding", "BC");
            dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, generateIv());
            byte[] dec = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText);

            byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);
            return new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return null;
     }

     public static IvParameterSpec generateIv() {
         byte[] iv = new byte[16];
         new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
         return new IvParameterSpec(iv);
     }
}
```

Comment: You use a random IV during decryption. This is wrong, you have to use the IV that was applied during encryption. Also, SIC (or CTR) is a stream cipher mode and doesn't actually need padding  (of course, if you have padded when encrypting, you have to unpad when decrypting).

Comment: Thank you, it works when i use the same IV that was used on encryption. But is it possible to get the IV from the ciphertext ?

Comment: For this purpose, IV and ciphertext must be concatenated during encryption. This is even a common approach (note that the IV is not secret). During decryption, both can then be separated due to the known length of the IV.